# Can MySQL handle a string 2 million characters long in BLOB

Tags: php, mysql

A search using the title returned 1 question on Stack Overflow, which was not related, and with the MySQL docs 65535 characters was mentioned as a max; but is that ... normal characters or would it be only about a fifth of that?  I need to figure this out in order to decide whether to try putting thousands of pieces of data like this, *0A1D2A3B* ... into one admittedly very wide column so it can be read once and then acted on by php for string manipulation, or, to put all those pieces of data into rows, one per row.

I would imagine it to be faster to get a single column read, and search a very long string than to read tens of thousands of rows into an array and then too, I find it easier working with strings than arrays in php.

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/ Use MySQL Full-text Searching. LONGBLOB , LONGTEXT 4294967295 (2^32 - 1) Or (2^32 - 2)/2 - UTF8 symbols.

Comment: Great resource, I will read it in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Can MySQL handle a string 2 million characters long in BLOB?

The maximum size of a `BLOB` is `65535` bytes.

However if you want to store larger values you can use a `MEDIUMBLOB` (`16,777,215` bytes) or a `LONGBLOB` (`4G` bytes).

Note:

- When using a Unicode character set not all characters use the same number of bytes and can require up to three (four) bytes per character.

However:

> The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type, but **the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of the communications buffers.**

---

#### UTF-8 is what I will be putting in there

> The utf8 character set is the same in MySQL 5.7 as before 5.7 and has
> exactly the same characteristics:
>
> - No support for supplementary characters (BMP characters only).
> - **A maximum of three bytes per multibyte character**.

---

#### What is a BLOB?

> A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data. The four BLOB types are TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and LONGBLOB. These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold. The four TEXT types are TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT. These correspond to the four BLOB types and have the same maximum lengths and storage requirements. See [Section 11.7, “Data Type Storage Requirements”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html)

...

> **The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type, but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of the communications buffers.** You can change the message buffer size by changing the value of the max_allowed_packet variable, but you must do so for both the server and your client program.

Source [11.4.3 The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html):

---

#### Storage Requirements for String Types

> In the following table, M represents the declared column length in characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string types. L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.
>
> [image]

...

> This page lists the BLOB and TEXT types and gives a formula for
> calculating the storage required, but it does not give the different
> maximum sizes. Here they are:
>
> - TINYTEXT - 255 bytes
> - TEXT - 65535 bytes
> - MEDIUMTEXT - 16,777,215 bytes (2^24 - 1)
> - LONGTEXT - 4G bytes (2^32 – 1)
> - TINYBLOB - 255 bytes
> - BLOB - 65535 bytes
> - MEDIUMBLOB - 16,777,215 bytes (2^24 - 1)
> - LONGBLOB - 4G bytes (2^32 – 1)

Source [Section 11.7 Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html):

Comment: Okay! that is encouraging.  I should have mentioned, UTF-8 is what I will be putting in there.  In any case, these formulas; I will work them but that looks like it can handle it all with ease. (still unsure about the server to client issue, but I don't envision it being necessary to address; the work will be done on the server. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MountainMan  See [10.1.10.5 The utf8 Character Set (3-Byte UTF-8 Unicode Encoding)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) if you are using `UTF-8`. Uses a maximum of 3 bytes per character.